# Triangular Layout of text in Latex

Tags: text-decorations, layout

My apologies if this is a basic question. In Latex, is it possible to set text in a triangular shape, as was often done at the end of chapters in Early Modern typography? I imagine it would be easy for a package to do. For an example of what I'd like to do, see this page from the Book of Common Prayer:

[image: BCP_page]

Comment: You could take a look at the [shapepar](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) package.

Comment: @Marijn Being a duplicate implies that he's asking for the same thing, it's not. It's just about the same package (or at least, it can be as it might not be the only one), but the application is different.

Comment: @Alenanno this question asks "how can I set text in a triangular shape", and the other question asks "how can I set text in a triangular shape" - that is more or less literally the title of the other question. Also the proposed solution is the same, i.e., define a shape with `shapepar` and set a paragraph to it. The only difference is that this question wants the triangle to be _down_ whereas the other questions asks for the triangle to be _up_, but that seems to be a minor difference.

Comment: @Marijn even so, I have the feeling that the next question will be "I copied the code from this question but how do I turn it upside down?" lol. But in any case, you have a point, I have voted to close as duplicate.